# file upload finish remove file name?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs,my problem is after upload file the file name is still on brows button.i want delete filename after upload a file,after upload a file (upload complete) i want to show no file selected.
this is my example. [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/7xebmn29/)

Comment: Can you show what you have done?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7xebmn29/

Comment: choose file to select any image.after the file name is displaying.it's ok.After upload hoe to remove the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fiddle Demo having errors

- `Angular library not included`
- Missing `ng-app="myApp"`

Consider following code its working as you want:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.upload = function(){
        alert('Removing file');
        $scope.myFile = "";
    };
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/824Ldzd8/)

Comment: Welcome @srkprasad. Enjoy scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Write this css for that.

```
input[type="file"]{
width:90px; /*reduce input width*/
color: transparent /*text will be there but not visible*/
}
```

or

```
input[type="file"]{
    color: transparent; /*text will be there but not visible*/
}
```

Comment: but i want after upload the filename hide